# What is the significance of xtb message: Interaction energies are not physical?

Tags: molecular-interactions, xtb, dftb-plus

I have been exploring xtb and used it to run docking on an ion pair. I get
the message at the end in the .log file. The xyz files of input structures
were obtained from Gaussian output files. Is there a way to optimize
monomers using xtb before submission so that the interaction energies
output are deemed physical? I am unsure of how to solve this issue. All advice is highly appreciated.

Thank you,

---

```
 Interaction energies
 Attention: monomers are not optimized
 Interaction energies are not physical
```

Comment: I think that the docking module should be used only to have starting structures for further complex optimization.

Comment: Thanks! That's my goal as well – however, I was not sure if there's something that I am missing in terms of using xtb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message states

> Interaction energies
>
> Attention: monomers are not optimized
>
> Interaction energies are not physical

This suggests that the interaction energy is computed as `E(interaction) = E(aggregate) - sum[E(monomer)]`. The true interaction energy is the difference of the optimized aggregate to the optimized monomers. Looking into the source code, this warning arises at

https://github.com/grimme-lab/xtb/blob/0e66cab758133bcaa6ea2bb59012a1603166e6fd/src/docking/search_nci.f90#L964

The warning appears to be issued always, suggesting that it is just to inform you that the interaction energy estimates are not accurate.